# What would you call the terminal leaf of a human organisation in layman term?

Tags: phrase-requests

Let's say you represent a human organisation with a tree data structure (organisation of a company, or for example for the USA you have the federal state then Texas inside it, then the county, then the township, etc.).

How would you say 
"*This entity does not have anything inside it, it's a leaf or a terminal node in my tree structure*" without using computer science term. If we were speaking about a genealogy tree it would be "*This person did not have any child*". Only I want a term that is **applicable for an administrative entity**, inside other administrative entities, **not a person**.

How is it possible to tell "*The [Escuadra de maniobra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidad_militar) does not rule over any other spanish military entity*" or "*The civil township is one of the possible lowest level of administrative division in the USA*"?

Comment: You've arrived at the [low man on the totem pole](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/low+man+on+the+totem+pole).  Not offering as an answer as it sounds like you want a formal term, and this is an informal idiom.

Comment: How about clerk?

Comment: Given your [comment to Laurel's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347623/what-would-you-call-the-terminal-leaf-of-a-human-organisation-in-layman-term#comment804886_347651), it's a little unclear exactly what you're after. Please [edit] your question to add a sample sentence. E.g. "When I first joined this company, I was assigned the ___ of the company.", or "Without anyone reporting to programmers, they constitute a/an ___ of this company.".

Comment: Do you have names for the tiers in your hierarchy? For example, Country, State, County, City. If so, can you define that the City is the lowest tier?

Comment: You could have an "Indian reservation" that is the lowest level of a specific branch and that is not the "Town".

Comment: These people are sometimes called “*individual contributors*” as opposed to leads, managers, directors, etc.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary There are deputy clerks.  Also, within towns, there are departments (parks, roads, police, fire, law, revenue, etc.), and within departments there may be managers who have teams, composed of different individuals or sub-teams with different responsibilities.

Comment: Oh!! “*Unless*” (above) equals ***only*** or ***except***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, you could say that the administrative division is ***[atomic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/atomic)***.

> Of or forming a single irreducible unit or component in a larger system

[ODO sense 1.2]

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to someone/something [**at the bottom of the ladder**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+the+bottom+of+the+ladder) (see also [corporate ladder](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/corporate-ladder.asp)).

There are several similar idioms:

- At the bottom of the...

  - ...[food chain](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+the+bottom+of+the+food+chain)
  - ...[totem pole](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/19956/191178)

In a word, an employee at that level is a **grunt**:

> a person with little or no authority in some organization; UNDERLING, SUBORDINATE.
>   <sub>-[Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/grunt)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm searching for a designation for this person workgroup/departement. I should have made clear that the entity was not a human but an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

***nonsupervisory***

Wiktionary:

> *Adjective* **[nonsupervisory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonsupervisory)** ‎(not comparable):
>
> Not of a **supervisory** character; not engaged in supervision : a
>   nonsupervisory worker
>
> *Adjective*
>   **[supervisory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supervisory)** ‎(comparative more supervisory, superlative most supervisory):
>
> Of, pertaining to, or in the capacity of a **supervisor**
>
> *Noun*
>   **[supervisor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supervisor)** ‎(plural supervisors):
>
> (management) A person with the official task of overseeing the work of
>   a person or group, or of other operations and activities.